# How to place a red circle in top right corner of centered div?

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a little css problem, and i dont know of its completely possible to do this in css, but i accept any other solution aswell.
Here i have an example of what i am trying to accomplish.

[image: example]

I am trying to add the red circles in the top right of the divisions.
My code sofar:

**HTML**

```
<div class="w3-container customheight">
  <div class="center buttons">
    <a class="todo roundbutton">
      <div class="redicon"></div>
      <div class="redicontext">
        <span class="todotext">1</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="decision roundbutton">
      <div class="redicontext">
        <span class="decisiontext">2</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="remark roundbutton">
      <div class="redicontext"></div>
        <span class="remarktext">3</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.roundbutton{
  width: calc(33.333% - 20px);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display:block;
  background-size: contain;
  float:left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}

.todo{
  background-image: url("../img/todo.jpg"); 
}

.decision{
  background-image: url("../img/decision.jpg"); 
}

.remark{
  background-image: url("../img/remark.jpg"); 
}   

.redicon{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 3%;
  background: red;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100%;

}

.redicontext{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 3%;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

I tried multiple things already:
  - creating another div behind the first one to use padding on that div without creating an ovale
  - absolute values for the red circles, this can be used with a certain height and width, but it has to work responsive.

I am not that good in css, but i know the basics. 
Any help on this is really nice!

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `relative` position and position the circle.

```
.redicon{
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  background: red;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.center{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.roundbutton{
  width: calc(33.333% - 20px);
  height: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display:block;
  background-size: contain;
  float:left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}

.todo{
  background-image: url("//placehold.it/150");
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.decision{
  background-image: url("//placehold.it/150");
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.remark{
  background-image: url("//placehold.it/150");
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}   

.redicon{
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  background: red;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.redicontext{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 3%;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container customheight" style="width: 450px;">
  <div class="center buttons">
    <a class="todo roundbutton">
      <div class="redicon"></div>
      <div class="redicontext">
        <span class="todotext">1</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="decision roundbutton">
      <div class="redicontext">
        <span class="decisiontext">2</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="remark roundbutton">
      <div class="redicontext">
        <span class="remarktext">3</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]